# convert JSONObject to ContentValues

Tags: android, json

I want to convert JSONObject to ContentValue. How can i do that without knowing what columns i have in JSONObject?

columns in JSONObject are the same as columns in SQLite database on the device and they are in the same order.

I can do it like this

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put(TASK_NAME, json.getString("name"));
values.put(TASK_KEY_PROJECT, json.getString("project"));
values.put(TASK_KEY_CATEGORY, json.getString("category"));
values.put(TASK_KEY_TAG, json.getString("tag")); //TODO CATCH NO TAG EXCEPTION
```

but i want to know better way
thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can both use `optString` or check with the method `has`.

For instance:

```
values.put(TASK_KEY_TAG, json.optString("tag"));
```

`optString` returns null if the key is not available. Or

```
if (json.has("tag")) {
    values.put(TASK_KEY_TAG, json.optString("tag"));
}
```